# Get Icon Image from the Title Bar of the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I m using Netbeans IDE, I need to get the icon from the title bar of the JFrame and set it in the JButton. Is there any way to get the Icon image from the JFrame, there is no getIconImage() method i tried getIconImages() but it doesnt works.

Comment: Have you tried to use the getIconImage() method?

Comment: Remembering which image you set is probably going to work out as a better strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Frame` (the superclass of `JFrame`) has [`Frame.getIconImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getIconImage%28%29). You should be able to use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Image image =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/resources/agfa_icon.jpg"));
setIconImage(image);
```

Credit: Alain Demortier, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192901/3308545)