# How would you change your programs Icon instead of the default java icon

Tags: java, eclipse, icons

This shows the icon when I launch through eclipse, but when I export it to a Runnable Jar It shows the default Java icon, I do not want to use the Resource way of doing it since it doesn't work in the IDE even.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Game component = new Game();
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("res/game.png");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(component);
    frame.setTitle(NAME);
    frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    component.start();
}
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815033/how-to-change-java-icon-in-a-jframe

Comment: As I said I don't want to use the Resource method I want to use this method as it is the better way

Comment: Then, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614772/how-to-change-jframe-icon

Comment: Thats the one I wrote this off of, and It will only work If I have the res/game.png in the same directory as my game.jar

Comment: oh i see. So, where is your res/game.png placed then? Inside `src` folder?

Comment: No Its in Project Name/res/game.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following code to set the iconImage to the frame:

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("res/game.png").getImage());
```

Even in this [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) you can find this same approach.

**Edit**:
Have you tried this code. It might be helpful:

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIO.read(new File("res/game.png")));
```

Check out this [explation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306872/seticonimage-only-works-in-eclipse-doesnt-work-when-exported-as-runnable-jar-fi) too.

Comment: frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("res/game.png").getImage());

Works in the IDE, but once I export and run through .jar, doesn't work

Comment: oh ok..then we might have a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

please use the following code

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/icon.png"));
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(image).getImage());
```

and put your icon file in `res` folder of `src` folder. But it'll display the icon of frame when you execute the jar file. Working fine for me.

Comment: The code looks like 
  try {
   Image image = ImageIO.read(Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/icon.png"));
   frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(image).getImage());
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

But I get the following error 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at package.Game.main(Game.java:51)

Comment: Problem was the path that I was using

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the wrong run as file, a stupid mistake but thats what I get for not having my Workspace clean.

I'd like to thank everyone who tried to help.