# How to change the icon image of your java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, icons

I'm trying to change the icon of my java project that appears on the desktop/folders/etc.

Currently has the default java icon:
[Default Java Desktop Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVYou.png)

How do I go about changing this?
NOTE: I'm using Eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change executable jar file icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590885/how-to-change-executable-jar-file-icon)

Comment: answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137088/how-would-you-change-your-programs-icon-instead-of-the-default-java-icon

Comment: *Confused:* An Eclipse Java Project is a *folder* and it doesn't have an icon, other than the default folder icon, e.g. . So what "Java Project" icon are you talking about?